# cec-client works when run from cli but not from cron

Tags: raspbian, cron

So when I run either of the following from the cli (SSH session) my pi will turn on my Samsung TV:

```
echo "as" | cec-client -s
echo "on 0" | cec-client -s
```

However when I but either of these into cron via crontab -e nothing happens. An example of what I have in the cron file is:

```
0 8 * * * echo "on 0" | cec-client -s
```

If i try add >> /home/pi/log to that line I get an empty file called log in my home directory.

How can I debug this? Or, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is a path issue. Adding the full path to the cec-client binary solves the problem.

E.g.

```
0 8 * * * echo "on 0" | /usr/local/bin/cec-client -s
```

Comment: That is by design cron doesn't run as your user so does not have the $PATH environment variable set.